# Rails: How to preload a message to user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails based prelaunch site that has some rotating background images (which are important for selling the idea of the site) that are taking too long to load, such that the users are leaving the site before they load. The only thing they're seeing is the email submission box.

What's a good way to show a message to the users that the site will take some time to load but then have that message disappear after a reasonable period of time. I'm guessing a jQuery fadeOut() with a timer, but I'm not sure how long to set the timer for, because I'm not sure at what time it would start counting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to deal with a situation like this before in an app that I wrote, so hopefully my suggestion will be of some help! I would:

1. Load a very basic DOM markup that is as barebones as possible. Barebones as in no assets loaded externally, just pure html tags and css.  This should load very quickly.  Have a div that contains some sort of message that let's the user know that the images are loading (e.g. `<div class = 'loading_images'>loading...</div>`)
2. Since you mentioned jQuery, I'll assume you have access to it, otherwise you could just use standard Javascript for this bit. The idea here is to retrieve the images you're trying to load using AJAX, insert the images into whatever DOM elements they need to be put into once they've been retrieved, then dismiss the loading message once that's all done.  This way, you don't have to worry about setting timers and guessing how long the request will take to complete.  Once the request is completed, you can dismiss the loading message and go on your merry way.  Wherever you include your jQuery, put something like this in the document.ready handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var request = $.ajax({
                        url:url_to_your_image,
                        type:"GET",
                        success:function(data){
                                $(whatever_context_or_div_to_insert_your_image).html(data)
                                $('.loading_images').hide()
                                }  
                      });
  })
```

This code will wait until the DOM is loaded, then create a new AJAX request to retrieve the image you want to insert into the page.  If the image is loaded successfully, the success method is called with the image (the variable named 'data'), and then inserted into wherever you want it to go.  Finally, the loading message is hidden so that the user can interact fully with the page and its contents.

There are two important things to note here:

- As it stands, the code won't do anything if the request fails (e.g. the images aren't loaded successfully through AJAX).  For how to handle that case, see the jQuery docs for $.ajax and error callbacks.
- The way the code snippet above is written, only one image will be loaded.  For a quick hack to load however many images you have, you can encompass the AJAX request in a for loop and load your images that way.  That's not good practice though, so I would instead suggest that you consider creating a single image sprite, retrieving only that image sprite via AJAX, and then using CSS to clip the smaller images out of the larger one.